# Crossover operator in genetic algorithms in Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms

I am developing a neural network that is trained using a genetic algorithm. 
The neural network is a multilayer perceptron using $\tanh$ as its activation function. Currently, the genotype of the neural network is by its weights. I used the method of making a connectivity matrix and linearizing it according to this paper: http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/keel/articulo/NN-Garcia05.pdf

What is a good crossover method for this? I've tried uniform crossover but it is too disruptive as there is no improvement whatsoever. Single-point crossover is discouraged as I have read, so what should I use?

Comment: Training by backpropagation / gradient descent is likely to be much more effective than training with a genetic algorithm.

Comment: I've actually successfully done backpropagation/gradient descent. This is just something more that I wanted to do. I know that there are better reinforcement learning methods but I just want to use genetic algorithms right now.

Comment: Why are you doing crossover? For genetic algorithms, crossover is optional not a requirement.

Comment: @Ray Well, if you're doing genetic algorithms without crossover, you're actually doing a population based random search... crossover is the very essence of GAs.

Comment: @Pal  GA with mutation is not random because of the selection operator; you only mutate the top fittest. It's more like random hill climbing. Adding a crossover step does nothing. If you think it adds something, I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should.

But, supposing the structure is the same in all individuals, you could take a random set of nodes from one, and the rest from the other, and just keep all out edges from nodes you selected.

Another alternative is taking a random set of edges from one, and the rest from the other.

A third alternative is to take the first $\ell$ layers from the first individual and the last $L-\ell$ layers from the second individual.

As you can see, there are very many approaches, and I don't think any of them will be satisfactory, but I hope you try and see for yourself.